# Full Screen Picture Background - Room For Footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I am beating my head against a wall on this one. I am trying to design a landing page, with a full screen picture background, that stops at the footer. So essentially I believe my trouble lies in creating a sticky footer..

I have been following the tutorial at [this website](http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/).

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <code omitted>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="bkgcontainer"></div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <address>
            <code omitted>
        </address>
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto -25px;
}
footer, .push {
    height: 25px;
}

#bkgcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto -25px;
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;  
    display: block;
}

footer{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}
```

As far as I can tell, I have everything set right. But when I launch the website, 'bkgcontainer' takes up the full screen and the bottom margin '-25' is below the view-port. I'm at a loss, any ideas? Fixes or better ways, I'm all ears.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: Haven't managed the time to get back to this project. I'll post back when I do.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the picture background take up 90% of the screen height, make the footer 10%, and pin the footer to the bottom of the page:

```
//remove `footer`
.push {
    height: 25px;
}

//set height to 90%;
#bkgcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto -25px;
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;  
    display: block;
}

//change height to 10%, change to fixed position, and set bottom to 0. Oh, set width, too.
footer{
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/vywapLk6/1/) to see how it looks.

Comment: This assumes you are putting your image in the `#bkgcontainer` div.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a completely different solution. Note that it doesn't contain a modification of your code, however, it is an entirely different solution (out of several solutions) to get a header and a footer

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    this is header
</header>
<div id="content">
   hello
</div>
<footer>
    this is footer
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: green;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
#content {
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Beautiful-Wallpapers-7.jpg");
     background-size: 100%;
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harshulpandav/7S4Xx/214/

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `position:fixed` for footer class

```
footer{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the min-height value on the #wrapper to either a smaller percentage value or a minimum pixel value to allow for the footer to display. What you have done is tell the browser that you want that div to extend no less than the full screen.